# Can't fetch data from an NBA stats API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am somewhat new to using fetch() and am having trouble retrieving data from an API.

```
function getStats() {

var url = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=";

var api = url;

fetch(api)
.then(function(response){
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data){
 console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error){
   console.log("There is an error.", error);
})
}
```

The console is logging --> "There is an error." [object Error] {}

I have tried this approach with two other JSON APIs and it has worked fine, just curious if I am missing something with this specific API.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually check your URL?  The query parameters all have no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`

It looks like this API is locked down. You may have to look in the API documentation to learn how you can access this API with a script on a separate domain.

According to [this](https://github.com/bttmly/nba), you may only be able to use this API server-side.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This definitely seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jsonp instead, or maybe using the mode 'no-cors' with fetch:

```
    fetch(api , {
      mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
    })
    .then(function(response){
     return response.json();
   })
```

[See it here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api)